# Documentation peer review

Tags: support, review-queues, documentation, documentation-editor

When an edit on Q/A enters the peer review phase it's possible for the editor to see how the review process is going, is there something similar for `Documentation` peer review?

Right now I can only see an `Awaiting approval` message but I can't find a way to see if the edit has already received some votes.

Is that because it hasn't been implemented yet or because there won't be this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the things identified as being needed is a more formal kind of review system, which is pretty high on the list of stuff that we're going to be working on.

I don't have *concrete* details on how we're going to do it yet, but it is going to be one of the first improvements that we make.

Comment: The sad part is - you can't implement it in an hour. It will take at least couple of days and by that time, the individual docs will the thoroughly FUBAR'ed.

Comment: @tereško I'm sure that we're going to need to do _some_ post-launch cleanup, but I don't think it's going to be the mess that you anticipate.