# Reviewing changes after the fact

Tags: discussion, review-queues, documentation

Each tag has its own "changelog", namely under the Activity tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23?tab=activity

Here all pending and approved edits to a tag are shown. However, some of those edits may have been approved by clueless reviewers and should actually not have been approved.

I think it would be very nice if Subject Matter Experts<sup>1</sup> could give their final say about certain edits. I imagine that looks something like this:

[image]

So that if a SME clicks the Review button, they can see the actual changes (instead of simply going to the topic) and annotate them as such:

- Looks great (gives extra rep to editor, automatic upvote, ...?)
- Looks OK (no further action)
- Missed one or more of the requested fixes, namely... (showing flags that were supposedly handled by the edit)
- Does not follow the [agreed upon editing guidelines for this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328422/where-to-discuss-how-to-organize-documentation-for-a-tag-topic), namely...
- Introduces new problems, namely...
- Very inappropriate, because... (rolls back the edit and slaps the editor and approver(s) on the wrist)
- Not sure (Skip)

These reviews would then better indicate the quality of the edit.

Some notes:

- Multiple SMEs should review each edit.
- SMEs should be able to unilaterally reject or rollback edits.
- Edits/topics/examples that were reviewed should probably be indicated in some way on the documentation site.
- Topics/examples that are edited after a review should probably have their previous reviews invalidated in some way.

Somewhat related: [Documentation peer review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328863/documentation-peer-review), but that still seems to be about reviewing *before* approving an edit.

What do you think?

---

<sup>1</sup>: problem: how to define that someone is a Subject Matter Expert? For example if they hold a silver or gold Q&A badge holder in the given tag?

Comment: What if a SME wants to roll back a _old_ change? How would that work without causing conflicts with later edits?

Comment: @Cerbrus this isn't a feature request, it's a discussion. I really don't want to dive into implementation details here. That being said, as for the versioning of documentation itself: plenty of discussions exist on this subject already, especially branching and merging. That will solve that issue.

Comment: The whole question reads like a FR, though. Any way, Although I like the idea, I don't see how it could be implemented, practically.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, I don't see a trivial way to implement this as well - I just want to coin the discussion that some kind of expert should look at every change, either before or after it is applied. I tried to give this post an example of how to implement this, but maybe thanks to that it looks like a feature request indeed.

Comment: Can't SMEs just rollback or edit poorly reviewed changes themselves, without an extra button, right now?

Comment: @Mike I don't know, I don't visit docs that much anymore. I've been missing this on Main as well: just a list of all edits, which you can filter by tag, so you can see what others are doing.

Answer (score 1):

We don't just need Subject Matter Experts to do post approval reviews.  A lot of the "crap" is down to people who don't bother to look at the context:

- They create duplicative examples, topics and even books.
- They create and / or edit examples that have little value to readers.
- They insist on adding their bit to some ill-conceived "kitchen sink" article.

Unfortunately, Subject Matter Experts are not necessarily good at writing, editing and *organizing* documentation.  There is also a role for people with Editorial expertise.

I'm thinking that maybe we need a *separate* reputation scheme for the Documentation.