# Increase reputation requirement to edit certain topics in Documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, documentation

SO has a good documentation and we as users added, reviewed and edited topics to make them better, and it is a nice thing that editors can get some points as well as it's more encouraging!

Yet I noticed when I go through Documentation some users try to attach some content to the best topics just targeting the points.

---

**Okay, what do you mean by best topics @ Doc ?**

I would say the ones which gets noticed  the very first and the ones with more upvotes.

---

**Come on! Everyone loves to join it and there is a certain level of points they need to edit a post and we can review what they add**

Yes. Agreed! There are very good ones who review & edit posts yet I see low quality posts which got approved. I am not saying those posts/edits are wrong, but

1. If they are not related to that topic
2. If there is another sub-top exist for that specific subject
3. The content inside the edit does not address for the topic or whole users of that subject. (I can give examples if needed, which I rolled back)

---

**Got what you are saying, but isn't that the same thing we do when a particular question or an answer is posted @ SO?**

Yes & no, that's something particular to that post yet if the question is good, mods can protect it! When we review such a post edits we can see the number of votes, in Docs we don't see that. If votes are big in number we consider more about the quality of the change, even if there is a harm from someone it's only for that post, but this is a documentation feature where we all go through and it's open. The issue comes when some users edit posts to get the advantage of the points regardless of the quality.

---

**Any last words? And where's the question? What feature do you request ;)**

> Why don't we have a process to prevent topics from every edit? Let's
>   say as an example if a topic at Docs reached 50 upvotes, after that
>   users with 1000 points can only edit or review edits of that certain
>   topic. Those numbers are just to give an example, but isn't that good
>   to make a more quality documentation? Or something slimier like @takje  suggested > check the comments.

You might tell me, a user with 10K points who has no idea at all about a certain topic can do the same so with my suggestion. The issue is still there, yes but when we gain points we get more experience and well behavior right? So the damage can be there is minimal. Isn't it?

What if Doc topics has a feature to control over topic edits after they reached to a certain level by votes.That's the request!

---

**Why am I posting this?**

I believe in Documentation and if you go through it it's the best rather than a tutorial site or a YouTube session of videos! And it's a great way to start learning a new topic/subject that you have no idea about, so I would love to keep it clean and perfect!

---

**If your are down voting this because you don't have that much of points!**

1. It's your choice! Free free to use your vote.
2. Yet you can edit/add content to the Doc posts,till they reach to the best level.
3. There are suggestions like keep another site for points of Doc or just do not reword points, for me no that's not gonna work here!
4. If you disagree with this keep an eye on the most upvoted topics @ Doc, check how many edits are there per week, compare with another less points topic on the same page,compare the people who involved well that can be a research ;) .
5. When you review a post/edit you see only the name of the person nothing else and the details that user has been added do you think is this good thing when you reviewing a one,secondly I am not sure about this yet I did not got a fake Doc edit proposed by community bot to check weather I am concentrated or not?
6. If you are an editor once your post gets approved check who reviewed it, how many points they have, do thy have some knowledge in that background showing in their profiles
7. Finally who gets affected? Not the person who knows the subject but the ones who want to know that with too much unnecessary additional details.

Think and feel free to vote up/down/suggest!

Comment: Agreed, but my point is far from 1000 lol.

Comment: @ Putri Dewi Purnamasari well that's just a number its **not the exact** one,This is for argument so its up to all of us, point is have a look on the most up-voted topics @ Doc , i've noticed this for weeks even the topic is already covered some people try to add more & more content, and I have seen the person who review it always not form the same background so they sometimes accept the wrong thing! If we do this this advantage is not for me mostly new ones who read the Doc first, and I am **not saying** low point need not to to be allowed to edit,but protect the best topics :) for better Doc

Comment: What about looking at a person's knowledge of a certain language? E.g. you need at least a bronze badge for the tags involved.

Comment: @takje  well yes that's a good suggestion after a certain vote limit reached yet i am not sure about the number of users with 100 up points still its a good option  so have :)

Comment: @Charuක the bronze badge is just a suggestion of course. You could apply the same principle by requiring at least 100 rep from a certain tag.

Comment: @takje got it and makes more sense than my points thing! once you mentioned that quickly check couple of users major edits that rolled back(I think they will get the points anyway but the change is revert). indeed they have points but its like 20 , 30 points  with like 800 rep.good point from you

Comment: The real problem is that not all edits are equally good while they still gain the same amount of rep. In the normal Q&A, each answer is concise and edits only gain rep once. Therefore the long term goal is to contribute good answers. In Doc in contrary, the length of the examples often makes it difficult to work in parallel as we are used to in Q&A, while this is where competition thrives. Therefore, Doc needs a way to upvote individual edits. There is too much weight on moderation in my opinion and the voting system of the crowd lacks power to punish or reward individual contributors.

Comment: Your formatting is confusing... quote blocks for your own words, bold text in two different sizes for your interjector, assigning names that are never referred to again ("a topic called B"), a numbered list out of nowhere ... you could make this a lot clearer, I suspect. I have no idea what feature you're requesting nor why this is tagged "documentation editor"

Comment: @Frank sorry about that, i will try to make it bit clear used the quote section to highlight since it went big thanks for the comment i will try to make a better feel free to correct my mistakes :)

Comment: Guys English is my second language and it's not that good, edited as mush as i can to express my idea just because i thought it will be important to have a discussion on this topic.Without any code this is the largest post that i did @ so ever so there can be lot of mistakes, but i think you got the idea.If you think it needs and edit to make it better it am grateful and happy to see your edit.

Comment: Hmm... One solution would be that once an example reaches _N_ upvotes, a tag score equal to that example's upvotes is required to edit that example.  (i.e. 25 tag score if the topic has 25 upvotes, 50 tag score if it has 50 upvotes, etc.)  If the number of upvotes is less than _N_, this limit isn't imposed.  This way, anyone can edit the examples that need it most, but the ones that are demonstratably useful can only be edited by those who prove their knowledge.

Comment: See [Should people who've never asked or answered a question for C be allowed to review C documentation changes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339137/) amongst other related questions.  Also [Are bad documentation changes getting passed because of inexperienced reviewing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344483/)  I would not be surprised to find there are other closely related questions.

Comment: See [Documentation should be elitist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339902/documentation-should-be-elitist).

Comment: For what it's worth, many people felt inadequate to edit Documentation even if they very clearly were just the right people. I think there might have been a paradoxical increase in editing if there were a fairly minimal barrier to entry. The goal wouldn't be to block bad editors, but to encourage editors who actually knew what they were doing.